# Replacement for gpedit.msc in Windows 7 Home edition

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have been trying to edit the rights for an account on a Windows 7 Home Pro machine. I would normally use gpedit.msc to to this, but it [doesn't](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=gpedit.msc+missing+windows+7&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=93210ee8ecdbb10e) seem to be included in the home versions of 7.

What are my options for doing this type of config editing? I'm a developer, not a IT person / sysadmin.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't as pretty as gpedit.msc, but you can download an Excel Spreadsheet that lists all possible group policy settings and their related registry keys. You can then just change the reg key manually.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=18C90C80-8B0A-4906-A4F5-FF24CC2030FB&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks Matt. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: It doesn't help with many complex registry things automated in gpedit.
For example there's no solution to startup/shutdown logon/logoff scripts and many other things.