# In Windows 7 Home Premium, is it possible to grant a user account the "log on as a service" right and if so, how?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, windows-services

The title says it all. I need to have the ability for a local user account to log on as a service on a computer running Windows 7 Home Premium. In Windows 7 Ultimate, this is accomplished by going to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy and adding the user to the "Log on as a service" policy. In Home Premium, there is no Local Security Policy in the Control Panel.

Is there another way to add the use to that policy (i.e. registry setting) or is my only recourse to upgrade the computer to Windows 7 Professional?

Thanks in Advance,
Ryan

Comment: Does either `secpol.msc` or `gpedit.msc` exist?

Comment: No, neither of them are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Not exactly a duplicate but [Replacement for gpedit.msc in Windows 7 Home edition](https://superuser.com/questions/103683/replacement-for-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-edition) shows a generic way to set/change policies in Windows 7 Home.</strike>
Does not apply here, there is no equivalent registry path.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245207 you will need to add the SeServiceLogonRight to your account. Ways to accomplish this are shown on [Windows 7 equivalent for ntrights.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/309360/windows-7-equivalent-for-ntrights-exe). So one option should be to run `ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight –u your_account_name`

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this would work. As I was about to test it though, I realized that if you select a user account that doesn't have the "log on as service" right when configuring the logon account for a service, Windows 7 (Home Premium) simply grants the user that right. Oops. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative you can assign the service logon right (SeServiceLogonRight) through the Service Manager (services.msc)

1. Open Service Manager
2. Choose the service in question and select "Properties"
3. In the "Log On"-tab then enter the username and password and press Apply-button.
4. It will display a message box with the following message:

> The account "username" has been granted the Log On As Service right.