# How do I require password complexity in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login

Is there a way that I can require a Windows 7 user account to maintain a password with a certain level of complexity?

After expiration, I want to prevent a password such as `123` or `password`.

The Windows 7 machine that I want to accomplish this on is:

- Not on a domain
- Is Windows 7 Home Premium (therefore no Group Policy Editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it through Local Security Policy in Windows 7. To enable Local Security Policy see this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/441022/in-windows-7-home-premium-is-it-possible-to-grant-a-user-account-the-log-on-as)

> Once you Enable the local security policy
>
> 1.Type Local Security policy in search Box(other way can be achieved through control panel)
>   2.Expand Account Policies → Password Policy. In the Right pane, select and click Password must meet complexity requirements.
>
> Notable things while you set Password Complexity :
>
> - Not contain the user’s account name or parts of the user’s full name that exceed two consecutive characters
> - Be at least six characters in length
> - Contain characters from three of the following four categories:
>
>   - English uppercase characters (A through Z)
>   - English lowercase characters (a through z)
>   - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
>   - Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)
>   - Complexity requirements are enforced when passwords are changed or created.