# Microsoft Family Safety *Weekly* Time Limits?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry, parental-controls

I see there is a way to set daily time limits, but is there a way to set weekly time limits? I notice that the registry items are kept here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Parental Controls\Users\[UserID]` *(UserID being a long string of letters and number to specify the user)*.

Since I can't get the weekly time limits on the Family Safety interface, what registry item can I create/edit to set a weekly time limit? Or is there another way? Maybe `net user` in command prompt?

P.S. - No, I don't want to set 1 hr per day. I would rather it be 7 hours per week, and they can be used up in 1 day, or 2 days or 5 days, or whatever. But I want it to act like a weekly "budget" of hours, but when they're used up, they're used up.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible :/

Comment: [Anything is possible. :)](http://superuser.com/questions/879449/how-do-i-allow-a-standard-user-to-install-programs)